# Is it possible to lock an Android device from a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, locking

Would it be possible to prevent the user from accessing their device for a period of time say 1 minute from a Flutter application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are couple of plugins out there
you can check them

[One of the plugin to lock Screen](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lock_screen#-example-tab-)

if it doesn't help you can do it your self with native code via Method Channels

[Writing custom platform-specific code](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab)

Hope that will help you.